# UIAlertController message won't display

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have two UIAlertControllers that can potentially be displayed – one for registering an account, and one for logging into it. They can be presented with an optional message.

```
func present(alertController: UIAlertController? = nil, message: String? = nil) {
    self.currentAlertController = alertController ?? self.currentAlertController
    self.currentAlertController.message = message
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController?.present(self.currentAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And it look like the message is carried through the function.

[image: "Email or password invalid"]

But then it doesn't display.

[image: Nothing here]

I can't tell if I'm missing something basic, or there's just something about UIAlertController I'm not aware of.

Comment: why are you referencing the rootViewController and not the currentVC performing the operation resulting in the alert being shown?

Comment: Also I believe the message has to be set when it is initializer? Its also weird that you keep a reference to it :/ since you get all the callbacks you need when you make the actions ?

Comment: Try to present the alert and set the message after

Comment: The alert has to be presented by the view controller that is currently at the top of the navigation stack (the one that is currently visible).

Comment: @SeanLintern88 yeah, I'm kinda switching from one architectural pattern to another that makes it weird right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the present action and the setting of the message did the trick.

```
func present(alertController: UIAlertController? = nil, message: String? = nil) {
    self.currentAlertController = alertController ?? self.currentAlertController
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController?.present(self.currentAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.currentAlertController.message = message
}
```

Another thing is, when initializing the UIAlertController to begin with, if you want the message to start blank but allow it to be updated later, the message should be `""` as opposed to `nil`.